# How can I select values from multiple rows into columns of a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, EventInfo, that contains multiple rows of information relating to single events:

```
EventFK  ParameterType  Value
1        123            computer1
1        124            userX
1        124            20140318
2        123            computer2
2        124            userY
2        124            20140317
3        123            computer3
3        124            userX
3        124            20140318
```

I'm only interested in data for events 2 and 3. What I'd like to end up with is:

```
EventFK  PCName     UserName  Date
2        computer2  userY     20140317
3        computer3  userX     20140318
```

I've done this before using STUFF to concatenate multiple rows from EventInfo into a single comma-separated string.

I'm keen to end up with proper columns instead, in order that I can easily map this to a DataGridView from a C# Windows Forms application.

Can I do something with a temporary table - insert a new row based on the value of three SELECT statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT EventFK,MAX(PCName) as PCName, MAX(UserName) as UserName,MAX(Date) as Date 
FROM (
      SELECT EventFK,
         CASE ParameterType WHEN 123 THEN Value ELSE '' END as PCName ,
         CASE WHEN ParameterType= 124 AND value LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN Value ELSE '' END as UserName ,
         CASE WHEN ParameterType= 124 AND value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN Value ELSE '' END as Date 
      FROM TableName
     ) T
WHERE EventFK IN (2,3)
GROUP BY EventFK
```

The result is:

```
EVENTFK     PCNAME      USERNAME    DATE
2           computer2   userY       20140317
3           computer3   userX       20140318
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35c7a/34)

Comment: I can barely get my head around this but it's awesome - thank you.

Comment: @gf131072: `LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` means `only characters`. If you want to know how it works, just execute the inner query first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION` to assign a key to the values that you want to transpose to columns, then use that key to do the transposition as follows:

```
;with x as
(select EVENTFK, value val, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by eventfk order by parametertype, value) rn
from YourTable where EVENTFK <> 1),
r1 as (select EVENTFK rid1, val PCNAME from x where x.rn =1),
r2 as (select EVENTFK rid2, val DATE from x where x.rn =2),
r3 as (select EVENTFK rid3, val USERNAME from x where x.rn =3)
select distinct EVENTFK, PCNAME, USERNAME, DATE
from x inner join r1 on x.EVENTFK = r1.rid1
inner join r2 on x.EVENTFK = r2.rid2
inner join r3 on x.EVENTFK = r3.rid3
```